# Why is "deterrence” spelt with two r's?

Tags: etymology, orthography

Looking at a medium-sized word list, all words are written "erence" with the exception of "deterrence" and the name "Terrence". I can find 50 words ending in "erence".

What is different about deterrence? Does it have an odd etymology? Or is it used enough to maintain the odd spelling?

**Addendum**

Here are some words that end in `rence` taken from my list:

adherence,
belligerence,
circumference,
coherence,
coinherence,
conference,
countertransference,
decoherence,
deference,
difference,
imperence,
incoherence,
indifference,
inference,
inherence,
interference,
irreverence,
misinference,
misreference,
nonadherence,
nondeference,
noninterference,
nonpreference,
nonreference,
pre-adherence,
preconference,
preference,
pre-inference,
pre-interference,
prepreference,
pre-reference,
proconference,
reference,
reinterference,
retransference,
retrotransference,
reverence,
semicircumference,
semidifference,
subconference,
subreference,
superindifference,
superinference,
surreverence,
Terence,
therence,
transference,
unadherence,
unindifference,
unreverence.

Comment: Have you looked at [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=deterrence) or another etymological dictionary? It seems to come from the Latin *de+terrere*; compare "terrible". Can you indicate what similar words you're considering, and what you don't understand about their etymology?

Comment: No I hadn't looked into the etymology of deterrence. I asked the question here instead. The question is really why is deterrence different from every other word ending in "ence", so it is difficult to understand all of their etymologies, but I agree looking at some examples would be helpful.

Comment: _Terence_ is usually spelled with one 'r' (but people are free to spell their children's names any way they choose).

Comment: I don't think appeals to etymology are particularly helpful here. Sure - ***deter*** has its roots in Latin ***deterre***. But the first "similar" word I just checked was ***defer***, which comes from Latin ***differre***, which also has the double /r/. It may not be the *whole* answer, but I think it's relevant that ***deterrence*** has stress on the syllable immediately preceding the doubled letter, whereas most similar words normally just have a neutral schwa there.

Comment: ...I also think it's relevant that if I needed a term for "the act of deferring" (as in *delaying*, rather than *respectfully ceding authority*) and for some reason I didn't want to use the word ***deferral*** (double /r/, obviously), I'd prefer to spell that one ***deferrence***. That would reflect the fact that I'm pronouncing it with stress on the *second* syllable for that contrived meaning (whereas stress goes on the *first* syllable for the standard "respectful" sense).

Comment: From [Philosophy in the Modern World:](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsaRVfnsZqnJw2BUnSg4YcXxwYwEdA:1651230513784&q=%22the+notion+of+deferrence%22&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFot2Bkbn3AhULWsAKHS_BDJEQvgUoAXoECAEQOg&biw=1476&bih=703&dpr=1.25) *Consider the notion of '**deferrence**' (différance), in which Derrida took great pride. Deferrence is supposed to combine the notions of **deferring** (putting off) and **difference** (being distinct).* Which Google Books didn't initially find because it unilaterally changed my search from "the notion of deferrence" to **...deterrence**.

Comment: "different from every other word ending in -ence" ... such as *recurrence, abhorrence, conferrence*, and others?

Comment: **recurrence** ends in **urrence** not **errence**. `conferrence` might be another  example, but wiktionary says that conferrence is an archaic form of conference (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conferrence) and merriam webster says that conference is a more normal spelling (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conferrence)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spelling of *deterrence* is largely about its Latin etymology. The same goes for most (although not all) *-ence* words in general, as well as *-ent,* *-ant,* and *-ance* words.

The position of stress could have also have some relevance, but the stress difference between *deterrence* and *inference* etc. is itself most likely based on the different etymologies of the words. (In words fully formed within English, such as all words ending in *-ing* e.g. *deterring, inferring, preferring,* the position of stress in the base English verb is certainly relevant.)

#### *deterrence* comes from a Latin verb with the stem *deterre-*

The Latin verb that *deterrence* comes from is *deterrere,* first person singular *deterreo,* present participle *deterrens.* The stem has a double *-rr-* in it, so all forms of the verb have *-rr-.* We also find *-rr-* in *concurrence, recurrence, occurrence* from the Latin verb *currere, curro.*

The Latin verb that *deference* comes from is *differre,* first person singular *differo,* present participle *differens.* Although the infinitive form *differre* has a double *rr,* this double consonant is not actually part of the verb's stem: rather, the stem ends in only one *r,* and the second *r* comes from the infinitive suffix *-re* being added directly after the stem. That is, the infinitive is built as ***difer**- + -re* just as the infinitive *deterrere* is formed as ***deterre**- + -re.* Therefore, forms of *differre* other than the infinitive, such as the first person singular and the present participle *differens,* only have one *r.*

So the spellings of these words with *rr* and *r* respectively are both regular from the perspective of their etymologies.

#### The etymological sources of the list of *-erence* words

As you may have noticed, most of the words on your list can be grouped according to a small set of endings. The ones ending in *-ference* mostly come from *ferre, fero,* which was a common verb in Latin with many prefixed versions in use. (*Interference* is an exception: it's from a different source, and it is not built according to Latin rules of word formation.) The ones ending in *-herence* come from *haerere, haereo.* The point I'm getting at is that from the perspective of etymology, these are not all independent data points. If one of those two Latin verbs had happened to have a stem containing *-err-,* you'd see a lot more *-errence* spellings in English.

Comment: Spot on. What this illustrates is the statistical fallacy:  the statistic seems orthographically significant, until you take into account the morphology.  What is more, 'fero', along with 'sum', 'volo' and 'malo' are defective.  'Sum' is crazy, like our own copula (perhaps reflecting earlier origins).  They all have a doubled r/l/s in the present infinitive (ferre, velle, malle, esse); but the participles - apart from sum -  are like all 2nd or 3rd declension verbs (ferens, volens, malens) with a single 'r'/'l')  The noun from 'ferens' changes 's' into 't' and adds - 'ia'. [continued]

Comment: [continued] This makes it 'ferentia', which has never, as far as I know, been used EXCEPT in all its prepositional compounds, of which there are great hosts, because the verb 'fero' is so flexible (vague) in meaning.  As to the others, these follow the morphological rules:  'Reverence' from 'vereor' (I fear), 2nd declension: participle 'reverens', abstract noun changes 's' to 't' and adds 'ia' giving 'reverentia'.  Most words in the list in the question are compounds of the same basic word.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of only three three-syllable words that have the main accent on the second syllable and end in (to use Merriam-Webster's pronunciation symbols) the sounds "ərən(t)s": *deterrence* (which MW dates to 1861), *occurrence* (1539), and *transference* (1681). So from one point of view, the odd spelling out isn't the double-*r* *deterrence* but the single-*r* *transference*.

The earliest so-called pronouncing dictionary that I am aware of, William Johnston, [*A Pronouncing and Spelling Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=C45p8qZUYZEC&pg=PA1&dq=%22pronouncing+dictionary%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp3suar7_3AhVpHTQIHUZQCscQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22transferable%22&f=false) (1764) has an entry for *occurrence* (given as *occúrrence*), but not for *deterrence* (as one would expect) or *transference* (as one might not). The closest related terms that Johnston gives to those two terms are *detér* and *detérred* in the vicinity of *deterrence* and *tránsfer*, *transfér*, and *tránsferable* in the vicinity of *transference*. Clearly Johnston isn't advising readers about how to pronounce the words at the consonant-and-vowel level but only which syllable to emphasize.

Although Johnston doesn't explain the two pronunciations given for *transfer*, most English speakers today (and perhaps in his day) use *tránsfer* for the noun and *transfér* for the verb. Strikingly, however, most English speakers today—at least in the United States—accent the second syllable of *transferable*, not the first; in fact, *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) gives only the pronunciation "tran(t)s-'fər-ə-bəl" for the word, although it lists *transferrable* as a variant spelling of *transferable*. Johnston's treatment of *transferable* suggests that at some point in its early existence *transference* may have been pronounced with the accent on the first syllable, which would then make its single-*r* spelling consistent with such other three-syllable English words as *conference*, *deference*, *difference*, *inference*, *preference*, *reference*, *reverence*, *severance*, and *temperance*.

Likewise, James Barclay, [*A Complete and Universal English Dictionary on a New Plan*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IwZgAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22pronouncing+dictionary%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp3suar7_3AhVpHTQIHUZQCscQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22occu%20rrence%22&f=false) (1774) provides a pronunciation (or accented syllable) for *occurrence* ("occu'rrence") but nothing for *deterrence* or *transference*.

John Walker, [*A Critical Pronouncing Dictionary, and Expositor of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=q5tWAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA24-PA164&dq=%22A+Critical+Pronouncing+Dictionary,+and+Expositor+of+the+English+Language%22+1800&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRhZO14L_3AhUODDQIHU6wBzAQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=snippet&q=%22capable%20of%20being%20transferred%22&f=false), third edition (1802) offers the following entry for *transferable*:

> TRANSFERABLE trans-fer'-a-bl, or trans'-fer-a-bl. a. Capable of being transferred. | I have met with this very common and useful word in no Dictionary but Entick's, where the accent is very properly placed on the second syllable ; as all words of this form ought as much as possible to retain the accent of the verb from which they are derived.

The second edition of Walker's dictionary (1797) has no entry for *transferable*, although it does indicate that "trans-fer'" is the emphasis proper emphasis for the verb form of *transfer* and "trans'-fer" is the proper emphasis for the noun form. In the [sixth edition of Walker's dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=UPsTAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22pronouncing+dictionary%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju07T2uL_3AhUSOn0KHS48BKYQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22capable%20of%20being%20transferred%22&f=false) (1809), however, the entry lists both *transferable* and *transferrable* as acceptable spellings, each with its own pronunciation:

> TRANSFERABLE trans'-fer-a-bl, TRANSFERRABLE trans-fer'-a-bl, a. Capable of being transferred.

The entry then repeats the 1802 edition's comment about the propriety of retaining the accent used for source verbs in derived adjectives "of this form."

Noah Webster, *A Compendious Dictionary of the English Language* (1806) spells *transferrable* with a double *r* and puts the accent on the second syllable. However, Webster's massive *A Dictionary of the English Language* (1828) changes the spelling to *transferable* while retaining the accent on the second syllable. The 1840 edition of Webster's dictionary sticks with *transferable*, but it also includes for the first time an entry for *transferrence* (spelled with a double *r*:

> **TRANS-FER'RENCE,** *n.* Act of transferring.

The next major edition of *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1864) includes two spellings of the word, with a different accent for each:

> **Trans'ference,** *n.* Act of transferring; transfer.
>
> ...
>
> **Trans-fer'rence,** *n.* See TRANSFERENCE.

Evidently there was still some disagreement about how the word should be spelled and pronounced, with Webster's now favoring the *transference*/*trans'ference* option. The 1864 Webster's dictionary is also notable for marking the debut of *deterrence*:

> **De-ter'rence,** *n.* That which deters; a deterrent; a hinderance. {*Rare.*}

Just four years earlier, Joseph Worcester, *A Dictionary of the English Language* (1860) had listed *transferrence* as the only spelling for that noun but had omitted any mention of *deterrence* (although it did include an entry for *deterrent*).

*Webster's International Dictionary* (1890) retains the two spellings and the two pronunciations of *transference/transferrence* without change; but *Webster's New International Dictionary* (1909) lists only the spelling *transference*, giving it a variable pronunciation:

> **transference** (trăns'fẽr-ĕns; trăns-fûr'ĕns), *n*. Act of transferring; conveyance; passage; transfer.

This remains the order of presentation (and pronunciation preference) through the fourth edition of the *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary* series (1931). The *Fifth Collegiate* 1936), however, flips the pronunciation preference:

> **transference** (trăns-fûr'ĕns; trăns'fẽr-) *n.* **1.** Act of transferring; conveyance; passage; transfer; as ***thought transference*** (i.e., telepathy). **2.** *Psychoanalysis.* Direction of feeling and desires, esp. as unconsciously retained from childhood, toward a new object.

That order of pronunciation preference has remained unchanged in editions six (1949) through eleven (2003) of the *Collegiate Dictionary* series.

---

***Assessment***

The spelling and the accented second syllable of *deterrence* have been treated consistently in U.S. dictionaries since the word first appeared in the 1864 edition of Merriam-Webster's *An American Dictionary of the English Language*.

The history of *transference* is quite different. It first appears in a U.S. dictionary in the 1840 edition of Webster's unabridged dictionary with the spelling *transferrence* and an accented second syllable (however, this same dictionary spells *transferable* with a single *r*, despite accenting the second syllable of it as well). Then, from 1864 to 1908, Merriam-Webster's dictionaries list two forms of the word: *transference*, with the first syllable accented, and *transferrence*, with the second syllable accented.

In 1909, Merriam-Webster drops the entry for *transferrence* and moves the accented-second-syllable pronunciation to the entry for transference, while keeping the accented-first-syllable pronunciation in the primary position. Finally, in 1936, as use of *transference* in psychoanalysis receives attention in its definition for the first time, MW flips the order of preference to put the accented-second-syllable pronunciation first.

This record suggests that the inconsistent combination of spelling and pronunciation for *transference/transfer'ence* (versus *deterrence/deter'rence* and *occurrence/occur'rence*) may reflect, at least in part, the longtime alternative pronunciation preference for trans'ference during the critical period when the spelling was still being hashed out. As for the double *r* in *deterrence*, that spelling is consistent with the the accented second syllable of the word, which dictionaries have consistently reported since they first began including entries for the word.

---

***Side note: Instances of 'deterrence' from the 1700s***

Although Merriam-Webster give a first occurrence date of 1861 for *deterrence*, the word began appearing in print long before that year. A Google Books search turns up three instances from the eighteenth century.

From Thomas Cooper, "[Sketch of the Controversy of the Subject of Materialism](https://books.google.com/books?id=K7ZcAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA226&dq=%22deterrence%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEj4yAk8T3AhUtEEQIHfTuDPAQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22deterrence%22&f=false)" (read at the Manchester Society, January 17, 1787), reprinted in *Tracts, Ethical, Theological and Political* (1789):

> 11. The question has been discussed almost 2000 years : during which time, every thing that human ingenuity could suggest in defence of the separate existence of the soul, has been advanced. The opinion moreover had been supported, not only by the pecuniary emoluments, and the honours of establishments, but by the arm of the secular power. Every motive that men could have to adopt it, has been applied, and every motive of **deterrence** has been exhibited. Yet have some of the wisest and the best men of the present day among us, and not only so, but members of the established church, and of the highest rank therein, remained unconvinced, that this dogma of immaterialism is so uncontrovertibly evident as inn general has been supposed.

From "[Labour and Solitude More Rational Punishments Than Executions](https://books.google.com/books?id=zk4DAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA104&dq=%22deterrence%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEj4yAk8T3AhUtEEQIHfTuDPAQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22deterrence%22&f=false)," in in The Gentleman's Magazine (February 1788):

> The great defect in the punishments of this, and perhaps every other country, I apprehend to be this, that they answer very imperfectly either of the purposes for which punishments are principally intended, the reformation of the offender, or **deterrence** from the offence. The noise and bustle of a public execution, and the crimes which are committed at the very foot of the gallows, are too evident proofs, that little impression is made upon those for whose benefit it is particularly appointed.

And from "[The Trial at Large on an Action for Damages Brought ... by the Righ Hon. George Fred. Earl of Westmeath, Against the Honorable Augustus Cavendish Bradshaw, for Adultery with the Right Hon. Mary Anne, Countess of Westmeath](https://books.google.com/books?id=3yZIoAM_k7sC&pg=PA9&dq=%22deterrence%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEj4yAk8T3AhUtEEQIHfTuDPAQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22deterrence%22&f=false)" (February 20, 1796):

> It would appear in evidence, that when she [the Countess] had been driven from her own door in this carriage under a pretence of going to visit her friends, that instead of going to those friends, she had ordered her coachman to drive with the blinds up, to a remote part of the country, with Mr. Bradshaw, whom she took into her carriage on the way. These facts with a number of others would come out in evidence, and to that evidence he [the Solicitor General] would rather refer the gentlemen of the jury than by anticipating the detail—seem to aggravate a case which in itself was but too strong, and which he was confident must have that weight with respectable men bound upon their oaths to give an impartial verdict, and such an one, as while it made *some* reparation to the wounded feelings of his noble client, (for no sum of damages however great would make adequate atonement) would at the same time hold out an example for the **deterrence** of similar crimes and make some satisfaction to the violated laws of society.

Comment: Another pronunciation detail with regard to “deterrence” is that the vowel in the stressed syllable can be either the “merry” vowel, as in *errant, aberrant,* and *terror,* or the “furry” vowel, as in *deterring.*